# how to fix git clone authentication error?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to clone a sandbox repo i've setup on gitlab. When trying to clone i'm prompted with entering a username and password. I have setup 2fa so i'm using my 2fa token as the password. and my gitlab username as the username. But i am given the following error.

remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See https://gitlab.cim.rhul.ac.uk/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
fatal: Authentication failed for REPOURL

Just wondering if there is anything i am doing wrong.

I am using linux (manjaro specifically).

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the git protocol? Set up your ssh keys. Https is the default for git repo hosting but I find the original protocol to be much better.

Comment: that made me remember about personal tokens. ive sorted it now. thanks!